# Operate a switch from a USB port

Tags: usb, switches

I have almost no experience with electronics so this might be a stupid question.

I have a "switch" that I want to operate from a computer running Linux, it's actually two cables that I need to connect to each other closing the circuit for about 1 second. They operate at 5V.

I did some research and apparently I can do this with an Arduino, but since it seems like a very simple circuit I was wondering if I can build something with only a few components. I also found the Teensy board but it still seems overkill.

Any advice?

Comment: What about an USB-GPIO module ?

Comment: You can buy off-the-shelf USB relay modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with a microcontroller, and the hardware can be very simple, using something like a PIC18f4550 which can run at 5 volts, you would just need the PIC, a couple of decoupling capacitors, a transistor, relay and flyback diode; there would however be a fairly significant software burden.

A much better solution in your situation is to get a ready made unit off the shelf which provides this functionality, something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071VJ628X), though I have no experience with it so can't vouch for the quality, it just turned up with a quick google.